# Create a dynamic graphic in excel

Tags: excel, graph, graphics

I I have a table with names and in front of each name I have the value 1 for "success" or 0 "Faill" I want to represent them in a graph and for each name to take the color green if 1 and grey if 0, I want the graphic to be dynamic and to add or remove automatically the name each time I apply a filter.

Is that even possible to do with excel?!!!

And thank you in advance for your help

for exemple

| Name | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Brian | 0 |
| Emmy | 1 |
| David | 1 |
| Malcolm | 0 |

I tried a classic graph but that what I want as a result.

[image]

Comment: I imagine it would be a Bubble Chart with two series filled in different colours and with x and y-values chosen to get somewhere near a square layout - tricky but do-able I think.

Comment: thank you for your answer! could you suggest me how I can do it?!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had time to try it and will now be away for a few days. I do intend coming back to it next week because it is an interesting question.

Comment: What I will do is post a mock-up of it for say half an hour then delete it

Comment: Thank you  for that answer, I will try to build Something with it.

Comment: and I'm also curious how you will manage it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic version of the plot which works, at least on a small scale. You could automate it with VBA but I have chosen to use a couple of helper ranges on a separate sheet.

The formula for the 'Success' series is:

```
=LET(visible,BYROW(Sheet2!B2:B10,LAMBDA(r,SUBTOTAL(102,r))),
all,FILTER(Sheet2!A2:B10,visible),
success,FILTER(Sheet2!A2:B10,(Sheet2!B2:B10=1)*visible),
n,ROWS(all),
s,ROWS(success),
perRow,ROUNDUP(SQRT(n),0),
seq,SEQUENCE(s,1,0),
x,MOD(seq,perRow)+1,
y,QUOTIENT(seq,perRow)+1,
z,SIGN(x),
label,INDEX(success,0,1),
HSTACK(x,y,z,label))
```

and similarly for 'Fail':

```
=LET(visible,BYROW(Sheet2!B2:B10,LAMBDA(r,SUBTOTAL(102,r))),
all,FILTER(Sheet2!A2:B10,visible),
fail,FILTER(Sheet2!A2:B10,(Sheet2!B2:B10=0)*visible),
n,ROWS(all),
f,ROWS(fail),
perRow,ROUNDUP(SQRT(n),0),
seq,SEQUENCE(f,1,n-f),
x,MOD(seq,perRow)+1,
y,QUOTIENT(seq,perRow)+1,
z,SIGN(x),
label,INDEX(fail,0,1),
HSTACK(x,y,z,label))
```

The results appear on sheet 3:

[image]

Then the graph appears on (in my case) sheet 2:

[image]

And you can change the filter to update it:

[image]

The data setup for the graph looks like this:

[image]

data labels being added in a similar way in Format Data Labels:

[image]

To plot larger numbers of data points, you might have to expand the ranges and experiment with the global bubble size setting:

[image]

---

To be done - the way to address the bubble size issue will be the standard one of adding a series with a default bubble size of (say) 100  and hiding it, then setting the bubble size for the 'success' and 'fail' series to sqrt(n), the number of points to be plotted.